# Como enviar um objeto JSON numa requisição POST com ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, post

Preciso enviar um objeto json com ajax para um API externa porém não consigo incluir váriaveis no lugar de valores estáticos

```
var numSGPE = document.getElementById('numSGPE').value
var setor = document.getElementById('setor').value
var subTipo = document.getElementById('subTipo').value
var tipo = document.getElementById('subTipo').value

$.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost:8080/NumDocumentos",
    method : "POST",
    contentType : 'application/json',
    dataType : 'json',
    data : '{"especie":""+tipo+"", "gerencia":""+setor+"", "numSGPE":""+numSGPE+""}'
    }).done(function(res) {
      console.log(res)
    })
```

Se trocar as variaveis (`tipo`, `setor`, `numSGPE`) por valores estáticos funciona de boa, mas que mandar os valores conforme estão nessas variáveis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

Acontece que você está usando aspas simples `'` para abrir e fechar sua string, então você poderia fazer desse jeito:

```
data : '{"especie":"' + tipo + '", "gerencia":"' + setor + '", "numSGPE":"' + numSGPE + '"}';
```

Mas eu recomendo fortemente usar o `template strings`, que ficaria assim:

```
data : `{"especie":"${tipo}", "gerencia":"${setor}", "numSGPE":"${numSGPE}"}';
```

Comment: então não estou usuando nenhum framework tipo Angular ou React, é um html simples que tem uns inputs e um javascript que faz essa requisição no clique do botão, daí esses templates strigs não funcionam

Comment: o `template strings` é do JavaScript :)

Comment: Me desculpa pensei que o javascript vanilla não reconhecia ${} esse formato. Funcionou muito bem Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Apesar da resposta do @Lucas Bittencourt funcionar, uma opção mais simples e flexível é você utilizar o método [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

> O método `JSON.stringify()` converte valores em javascript para uma **String JSON**.

```js
const dadosForm = {
    numSGPE: document.getElementById('numSGPE').value,
    gerencia: document.getElementById('setor').value,
    especie: document.getElementById('subTipo').value
};

$.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost:8080/NumDocumentos",
    method : "POST",
    contentType : 'application/json',
    dataType : 'json',
    data : JSON.stringify(dadosForm)
}).done(function(res) {
    console.log(res)
});
```